# Check if my app is downloaded by clicking on Google Play link

Tags: android, google-play

I'm developing an android application.

In this application I have one button. If user clicks on this button it will be redirect on Google Play on a specific application link.

Is there any way to know if user have downloaded that application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Redirect to google play store:

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app_packge_name"));
startActivity(viewIntent);
```

or

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
Uri.parse("market://details?id=app_packge_name"));
startActivity(viewIntent);
```

To Check If application is Installed or not:

```
private boolean isPackageInstalled(String packagename, Context context) {
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(packagename, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

To Check if app install from google play store:

```
public static boolean isAppFromPlayStore(Context context, String packageName) {
     boolean result = false;
     String installer = context.getPackageManager()
                        .getInstallerPackageName(packageName);
     if(installer!=null && installer.equals("com.android.vending")){
          result = true;
     }
     return result;
}
```

Comment: Your solutions could works, is not very elegant but it's very useful. When should I use isPackegeInstalled() in my application for be sure that user have or not installed the application from Google Play?? I hope I was clear with my answer